# python - Is there a way to make a discord bot listen to another discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a program to create an endless loop,
for example:

**`bot1.py`**

```py
@bot.command()
async def loop1(ctx):
    await ctx.send('$loop2')
```

**`bot2.py`**

```py
@bot.command()
async def loop2(ctx):
    await ctx.send('$loop1')
```

But the main problem is a bot would not listen to another bot, so this won't work...

is there a way to make a bot listen to another bot? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Explain your user case and how would this be used and why.

Comment: I thought it would be interesting if that works? just for me to use i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of using the `async def` to define a command, you could use the `on_message` event.

**bot1.py:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('$loop1'):
     channel = message.channel
     await channel.send("$loop2")
```

**bot2.py:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('$loop2'):
     channel = message.channel
     await channel.send("$loop1")
```

not entirely sure if this will work, but you could try

Comment: Apparently it worked! Note that from the 3rd line onwards of both files needs to be indented and the last line of bot2.py needs to be ```await channel.send("$loop1")```